# Dcpromo failed - Ownership of FSMO role is set to a server which is deleted or does not exist

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domaincontroller

I am attempting to use dcpromo on a Windows 2008 R2 server.  The command produces a warning and an error in the event log. Below are the print outs of those entries:

---

-Warning-

Ownership of the following FSMO role is set to a server which is deleted or does not exist.

Operations which require contacting a FSMO operation master will fail until this condition is corrected.

FSMO Role: CN=Infrastructure,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=XXX,DC=XXXX 
FSMO Server DN: CN=NTDS Settings\0ADEL:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,CN=XXX-PDC01\0ADEL:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=XXX,DC=XXXX

User Action:

1. Determine which server should hold the role in question.
2. Configuration view may be out of date. If the server in question has been promoted recently, verify that the Configuration partition has replicated from the new server recently.  If the server in question has been demoted recently and the role transferred, verify that this server has replicated the partition (containing the latest role ownership) lately.
3. Determine whether the role is set properly on the FSMO role holder server. If the role is not set, utilize NTDSUTIL.EXE to transfer or seize the role. This may be done using the steps provided in KB articles 255504 and 324801 on http://support.microsoft.com.
4. Verify that replication of the FSMO partition between the FSMO role holder server and this server is occurring successfully.

The following operations may be impacted: 
Schema: You will no longer be able to modify the schema for this forest. 
Domain Naming: You will no longer be able to add or remove domains from this forest. 
PDC: You will no longer be able to perform primary domain controller operations, such as Group Policy updates and password resets for non-Active Directory Domain Services accounts. 
RID: You will not be able to allocation new security identifiers for new user accounts, computer accounts or security groups. 
Infrastructure: Cross-domain name references, such as universal group memberships, will not be updated properly if their target object is moved or renamed.

-Error-

The operations master roles held by this directory server could not transfer to the following remote directory server.

Remote directory server: 
\XXX-AWSDC2.CSI.local

This is preventing removal of this directory server.

User Action 
Investigate why the remote directory server might be unable to accept the operations master roles, or manually transfer all the roles that are held by this directory server to the remote directory server. Then, try to remove this directory server again.

Additional Data 
Error value:
5005 The directory service is missing mandatory configuration information, and is unable to determine the ownership of floating single-master operation roles. 
Extended error value:
0 
Internal ID:
52498782

---

The following roles have been successfully transferred to the XXX-awsdc2 server

Schema master
Domain naming master
PDC
RID pool manager
Infrastructure master

How do I remove the CN=CSI-PDC01 object using ADSI?  It looks like the XXX-PDC01 held the FSMO Server role at one point and then was removed from the domain with out being demoted properly.  I've been unable to find any reference to the XXX-PDC01 server anywhere in the DNS, AD or ADSI.

I've also attempted to delete all the AD metadata.  As a last resort, I could always use the dcpromo /forceremoval command but I'd prefer to work through the error and demote this domain controller using the dcpromo command without the forceremoval flag.

Thanks!

Comment: I used this resource to solve this issue.  Hopefully others can benefit.  

https://dailysysadmin.com/KB/Article/1039/active-directory-active-directory-could-not-transfer-the-remaining-data-the-operation-failed-could-not-transfer-the-remaining-zones-event-id-2091/